# Downloading TensorFlow BioBERT model

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

This command prompt is taking forever to download.

```
$ transformers-cli download model monologg/BioBERT
```

I executed the script within Python virtual environment (Python version is 3.10.12) and I have been waiting for over 16 hours.

Why does this happen?